# Group by the dates to weeks

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime

I have time in ms in epoch format, I need to translate this into a date and group it by a week number.

I tried the following procedure:

```
df.loc[0, 'seconds'] = df['seconds'].iloc[0]
for _, grp in df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper(key='seconds', freq='7D')):x
    print (grp)

df["week"].to_period(freq='w')
```

For example, if my 'seconds' column is presented like 1557499095332, then I want the 'dates' column to be 10-05-2019 20:08:15 and the 'Week' column to present W19 or 19.

How do I go about this?

Answer (score 2):

Try using strftime method:

```
from datetime import datetime as dt
x = 1557499095332
dt.fromtimestamp(x/1000).strftime("%A, %B %d, %Y %I:%M:%S")
dt.fromtimestamp(x/1000).strftime("%W")
```

3rd line will return 'Friday, May 10, 2019 03:38:15'

4th line will return '18' (it's because 1st of January 2019 will return '0' as it's first week)